# Register URL Prefix

Tags: c#, webrequest, .net-4.5

I have this URL:

"data:image/png;base64,....."

If I open it on Chrome, I receive an image, but I don´t know how to configure the prefix "data" using WebRequest.

```
WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("data", new CustomWebRequestCreator());
```

I have to build a custom creator based on "IWebRequestCreate" but I don´t know what do I have to implement there.

```
public class CustomWebRequestCreator: IWebRequestCreate
{
    public WebRequest Create(Uri uri)
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(HttpWebRequest),
                                    BindingFlags.CreateInstance | BindingFlags.Public |
                                    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
                                    null, new object[] { uri, null }, null) as HttpWebRequest;

        webRequest.UserAgent = "OMG IT WORKED!";
        return webRequest;
    }
}
```

I always get "remote name could not be resolved" when trying to make a GET request:

```
WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("data", new CustomWebRequestCreator());
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("data:image/png;base64,.....");
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse(); <-- EXCEPTION
```

Can anyone help me with that?

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you explain what you expect this call to do? Normally one would just get bytes directly from inline data directly without any additional requests... (assuming you are talking about [data uri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) ).

Comment: I expect that this call returns a bitmap image actually. Thanks for your help @AlexeiLevenkov

Comment: I see - I assume you've read whole [Programming pluggable protocols](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f6c88af%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) article set... You definitely should not be using HttpWebRequest  as data is present locally in the url. Possibly there are existing samples too.

Comment: It was my mistake.. I just don't know how to implement CustomWebRequestCreator @AlexeiLevenkov =)